# Linq to Entity - How to relate an entity to a store procedure

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have an entity table that is mapped to stored procedures in order to do all of the CRUD operations.  The retrieval procedures mapped to this table mirror the properties of the table as they should.  This same entity table has a one-to-reference with a lookup table.

I need to be able to access that lookup tables properties.  Is there a way to tie these two tables together using a stored proc for one table and querying the entity object for the lookup..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question? What do you mean by include?